# Django MongoDB Engine connection failure

Tags: django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

[SOLVED] After successfully completing the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), I have tried to use mongoDB as a database, with [Django MongoDB Engine](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/). This is the database configuration in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', 
        'NAME': 'test',                               
        'HOST': 'localhost',               
        'PORT': 27017,                   
#       'OPTIONS' : {
#           'slave_okay' : True,
#       }
    }
}
```

And this is the error message I get, after running `python manage.py syncdb`
:

```
raise AutoReconnect("could not find master/primary")
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not find master/primary
```

I got this error, even after shutting down the mongoDB server, so I figured out that this needed to be a connection issue. I posted an answer on how I solved this.

---

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64, Python 2.7, django 1.4.2, mongoDB x86_64 2.2.1 (clean new install)

Comment: did you set up a replica set?  If you are only connecting to a single server 'slave_okay' option doesn't make any sense...

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't use a replica set. Initially, I was not using the `OPTIONS` entry, but the error was exactly the same. I added it because I thought that it might help. With or without it, I get the same error.

Comment: invalid ns just means there is no users collection in the database you are connected to.  Your database is not corrupt - it apparently doesn't contain appropriate collections/schema that's expected.

Comment: how do you connect to your mongoDB with mongo shell?

Comment: I can connect through the `mongo` shell, yes, but not through the django app. But, I actually just solved the django `syncdb` problem.

Comment: maybe you can post what you had to do to solve it, as an answer (in case others might have the same problem)

Comment: Oh, I thought I couldn't answer with only 6 rep points.

Comment: I guess I should delete the second question from this post, an create a new one.

Comment: I posted the second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590638/mongodb-2-2-1-database-not-valid

Comment: @AsyaKamsky You are so right about the invalid ns! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved this is so simple that I am almost ashamed at myself for asking the question in the first place, but I hope it will be useful:

I simply upgraded the [Django MongoDB Engine](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/) by typing into the terminal:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine --upgrade
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running ...

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

... from the mongo terminal?

Comment: That, and starting `mongod --repair`, didn't help.

Comment: `db.repairDatabase()` reurns `{ "ok" : 1 }`. But after that, `db.users.validate()` returns the same `{ "errmsg" : "ns not found", "ok" : 0, "valid" : false }`, and I still cannot connect to the database with django.